# HLSL #pragma once equivalent?

Tags: include, shader, direct3d, hlsl, pragma

What's the equivalent to C/C++-like `#pragma once` in HLSL includes?

I want (as a contrived example):

```
// ./dependency.hlsl
float x() { return 0; }

// ./shader.hlsl
#include "./dependency.hlsl" // (./ unnecessary; for question readability)
#include "./dependency.hlsl"
```

to not fail with `error X3003: redefinition of 'x'`. `#pragma once` at the top of my file yields a non-error `warning X3568: 'once' : unknown pragma ignored` and does nothing!

Comment: "hlsl" "include guard" brings up only 135 results on google, none of which are relevant and "hlsl" "pragma once" brings up C++ stuff. Hopefully the Google gods catch this. Also, not sure if there's a better approach (I'm fairly newbie) so maybe my provided answer is nonoptimal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use C/C++ macro-like include guards. The contrived `dependency.hlsl` would look as follows:

```
#ifndef __DEPENDENCY_HLSL__
#define __DEPENDENCY_HLSL__

float x() { return 0; }

#endif // __DEPENDENCY_HLSL__
```